# How can I create whitelist of users allowed on a domain computer?

Tags: windows-server-2008, active-directory

I have a server with Windows Server 2008 which is joined to our local Active Directory Domain.  This means that anyone can access it by default, but only certain specific users are Administrators.  Instead, I would rather have it **only** allow a certain whitelist of users access to the computer.  Does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: When you say "anyone can access it", what are you referring to? Logging on to it?

Comment: Yes.  Anyone with a domain login is able to login to the computer.  This is what I want to restrict.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You would need to remove the 'domain users' from the local 'users' group. - that is where they are getting thier permissions to log into the machine.
2. Then create a new group in AD that has the people you want to access the machine.
3. Add that new group to the local 'users' group of the machine you want to limit.

Then you just need to add a user to the new group to give them permissions to log into the box.

Comment: Awesome!  This appears to be working properly.  Thanks very much.